# Unity - Button OnClick only execute the animation after I click in another button

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, vuforia

I have this 3 buttons

[image]

When I press the hit button, it plays one animation and the interactable button is set to off for a time period with "bt.interactable = false;".
After that time period, it is set to true.

[image]

And it let me play again after that time.

However, the second play of the animation only works if I play one of the other buttons before I play the "hit button" again.
This is the code that leads with the button timer:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ldbutton : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Image loading;
    public Button bt;
    int sec;
    string pl1_name = "Unicorn";
    public int counterclick;
    bool buttonLocked;
    Firebase_Bridge FB = new Firebase_Bridge();

    int tmp_sec;
    int totalSeconds = 0;
    int TOTAL_SECONDS = 0;

    async void Start()
    {

        if (bt.name.Equals("SpecialHitButton")){
            string time = await FB.LoadData_player_timeplsuperhit(pl1_name);
            sec = int.Parse(time);
        }
        if (bt.name.Equals("HitButton"))
        {
            string time = await FB.LoadData_player_timeplhit(pl1_name);
            sec = int.Parse(time);
        }
        if (bt.name.Equals("DefendButton"))
        {
            string time = await FB.LoadData_player_timepldefend(pl1_name);
            sec = int.Parse(time);
        }
        Debug.Log("star");
        tmp_sec = sec;

        bt.onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            loading.fillAmount = 1.0f;

            bt.interactable = false;

            if (counterclick < 2)
            {
                bt.interactable = false;

                sec = tmp_sec;
                if (sec > 0)
                {
                    bt.interactable = false;

                    totalSeconds += sec;
                }
                TOTAL_SECONDS = totalSeconds;
                StartCoroutine(second());
            }
        }
        );
} 
    IEnumerator second()
    {
        bt.interactable = false;

        Debug.Log("second");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        if (sec > 0)
        {
            sec--;

            fillLoading();
            StartCoroutine(second());

        }
        if (sec == 0)
        {
            counterclick = 0;
            totalSeconds = 0;
            TOTAL_SECONDS = 0;
            //sec = 0;
            StopCoroutine(second());

            Debug.Log("termina");

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            StartCoroutine(wait());


        }
    }
    IEnumerator wait ()
    {
        bt.interactable = true;
        bt.enabled=true;
        return null;

    }

    void fillLoading()
    {
        Debug.Log("fillLoading");

        totalSeconds--;
        float fill = (float)totalSeconds / tmp_sec;
        loading.fillAmount = fill;
        Debug.Log("update");


    }
}
```

And this my animator:
[image]

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: You probably need to show your code so that we can help you.

Comment: In the AnimationController have an empty animation for it to go to when it finishes, so it can be played again.

Comment: @akaBase you solved my problem! I created an empty state and now it worked! Thank you so much!